# Initializing a variable while concatenating another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this for loop with variable `value_from_db`

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

   var value_from_db = array[i].value;
}
```

However I need to make the variable `value_from_db_0, value_from_db_1, value_from_db_2` ... depending on i.

Something like:

```
var value_from_db_+i = array[i].value;
```

The purpose is

```
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
     if( array[i].condition == '0' ) {                                  

           jQuery("#username").on('change', function() {

            var value = this.value;         

            if( value === array[i].value ) {  //because array[i].value doesnot seem to work here
                count++;
                alert(count);
            } 
     }
}
```

because array[i].value doesnot seem to pass through the anonymous function, I am trying to differentiate the varialbe.

Comment: You should create an array and add your values into it

Comment: How do you plan to use these variables?

Comment: @igor I've edited the question, please have a look.

Comment: Oh, this is entirely different issue that has to do with closure and captured variable.

Comment: How many elements with `id="username"` do you have on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options here. The first obvious one is to use an array:

```
var value_from_db = array.map(item => item.value)
// then access them with the index directly
console.log(value_from_db[0])
```

But if you really want those variable names, you could house them within an object fairly easily:

```
var myObj = {}
array.forEach((item, i) => myObj[`value_from_db_${i}`] = item.value)
// the use with something like
console.log(myObj.value_from_db_0)
```

---

After reading the comments on @Igors closure answer, it looks like what you are trying to do (and this is best guess from the vague comment), is watch for changes to `#username`, and figure out if all the array values have been matched at one point or another. If I'm correct, you could do it like this:

```
// remove unwanted condition items
var conds = array.filter(item => item.condition === '0')
// watch for element changes
jQuery("#username").on('change', function() {
  var comparer = this.value
  // update a match key for any items where a match is found
  conds
    .filter(item => item.value === comparer)
    .forEach(item => item.match = true)

  // check if all matches have been found
  if(conds.every(item => item.match)){
    alert('all matched')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

After edit of the question this became an entirely different issue that has to do with closure and captured variable.

Potentially repeating calls `jQuery("#username").on('change', ...` look suspicious, but maybe there is only one `array[i].condition == '0'` in the array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  if( array[i].condition == '0' ) {                                  
    jQuery("#username").on('change', (function(aValue) {
      return function() {
        var value = this.value;         
        if (value === aValue) {
          count++;
          alert(count);
        }
      }; 
    })(array[i].value));
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. but count seems to be increasing on every change. What I need to check is if all condition inside for passes so I thought of matching `arrayLength` and `count` to know. However this doesnot seem to work. Can you please guide me on this.

Comment: @micky I would, only I have no idea what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I want to know if if condition passes over each iteration.